# If statement incorrectly recognising spaces in a bracket

Tags: c++

I am writing a mini programming language and I am currently working on my first proper command. My command is called 'prout("Sample text")'. When my program sees a space in between the letter t from the word prout and the opening bracket, it outputs an unexpected indent error, which is supposed to happen. What isn't supposed to happen is it recognising spaces in the text that the user wants to output and outputs an unexpected indent error. Does anybody know how to implement a way to stop the program from recognising that spaces in the text that the user wants to output is an unexpected indent error?

Here is the current output:

```
>>> prout("Hello")
Hello
>>> prout ("Hello")
Error: Unexpected indent //That is supposed to happen
>>> prout("Hello I am a programmer!")
Error: Unexpected indent //That is the problem
```

I've tried to use the attribute .npos to filter the spaces but this hasn't worked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "printoutput.h"
#include "Line.h"

using namespace std;

void printoutput::print(string input) {
    int i = 0;
    int length = input.length();
    if (input.find('(') != input.npos && (input.find(')') != input.npos) && (input.find('\"') != input.npos)) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
            char letter = input[i];
            if (input.find(' ') != input.npos && (i == 5)) {
                cout << "Error: Unexpected indent";
                break;
            }
            if ((letter == 'p') && (i != 0) || (letter == 'r') && (i != 1) || (letter == 'o') && (i != 2) || (letter == 'u') && (i != 3) || (letter == 't') && (i != 4) || (letter == '(') && (i != 5) || (letter == '\"') && (i != 6 && i != input.length() - 2) || (letter == ')') && (i != length - 1)) {
                char inputletter = input[i];
                cout << inputletter;
            }
            else if ((i != 0 && (i != 1) && (i != 2) && (i != 3) && (i != 4) && (i != 5)) && (i != 6 && i != length - 2) && (i != length - 1)) {
                char inputletter = input[i];
                cout << inputletter;
            }
        }
    }
    if (input.find('\"') == input.npos) {
        cout << "Syntax error: Missing quotation marks";
    }
    else if (input.find('(') == input.npos || (input.find(')')) == input.npos) {
        cout << "Syntax error: Missing parenthesis";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I expect the output to show the user's text that they have wanted to output with the spaces that they may have included.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some more reading on *tokenizing*, *lexing* and *parsing*.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what this line does

```
if (input.find(' ') != input.npos && (i == 5)) {
```

If says if the input contains a space and if `i` equals 5 then output an error. Since `i` loops through all the indexes of the string this will be true of **any** string of length at least 5, which contains a space **anywhere**.

I'm thinking that what you really meant is this

```
if (input[5] == ' ')
```

but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I will bear that in mind and let you know if I come up with the solution based on your opinion.

Comment: Just to let you know I have used your if statement method and it works! Thank you!